# Need help to structure my SQL DB - groups settings

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am trying to build a 'facebook groups' style application, which contains groups and each group has its own set of settings.

so I created 3 tables:

```
groups - (id, name..)
settings - (id, key)
groups_settings - (group_id, setting_id, value) group_id + setting_id are a primary key
```

and it works fine on single values settings (like min_age, max_age etc..).

but now I am facing a problem when I have a setting key which can have multiple values, for example: "allowed_countries" which is a list of allowed countries a user can join from.

I can't have multiple rows with the same group_id and setting_id, as they are under primary key constraint.

so how would you solve this problem? should I restructure my DB?

Comment: One possible solution without changing DB schema is to serialize your values as strings to store in DB and deserialize to whatever format you need on application level.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but I hope there is a better solution, as its really hard to query the field in that way.

Answer (score -1):

So you have a many-to-many relationship (users to countries.) One way to model this is to have a lookup table like so:

users table has primary key user_id (and other columns)
countries table has primary key country_id (and other columns)
user_country_mapping table has exactly two columns:

- user_id is a foreign key into users table
- country_id is a foreign key into countries table

That way, you can keep your data model clean.